# Ruby - Break a line after first word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have an attribute of an ActiveRecord model I'm printing to an ERB template, and I need to insert a 
 tag after the first word. Here's an example:

"Tori Atkins Wins" needs to read:

```
Tori<br />
Atkins Wins
```

I'm assuming this should be handled with a regex, but I'm not sure how. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: If you put HTML into your question, you need to format it as code in order for it to actually render as plain-text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing it in `ERB`:

```
<% "Tori Atkins Wins".split(" ",2).each do |str| %>
   <%=  str %> <br>
<% end %>
```

Replace `"Tori Atkins Wins"` with the `attribute` of your `Model`.

Here's how it looks in irb:

```
2.1.0 :106 >   "Tori Atkins Wins".split(" ",2)
 => ["Tori", "Atkins Wins"] ## Returns an array with 2 elements
```

Comment: better to use `/\s+/`,,, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it

```
<% split_attribute = @model.attribute.split(" ") %>
<%= split_attribute.shift %>
<%= split_attribute.join(" ") %>
```

`shift` pops the element from the array. `shift(n)` pops n elements from the beginning of the array.

Eg,

```
   >> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
   >> a.shift
   => 1
   >> a 
   => [2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-sub):

```
> "Tori Atkins Wins".sub(' ', '<br />')                    
=> "Tori<br />Atkins Wins"
```